# Can we limit parent in generateTreeList function?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I am using Cakephp Tree Behaviour to list hierarchical data.
Blow is the complete out put using generateTreeList function.

````
(
    [1] => Skoda
    [2] =>    Kushaq
    [3] =>    Taigun
    [4] => Maruti Suzuki
    [5] =>    Swift
    [9] =>       Swift VXI
    [11] =>          Swift VXI ABS
    [10] =>       Swift LXI
    [6] =>    Baleno
    [7] =>       Baleno RS
    [8] =>       Baleno LS
    [16] => Toyota
    [17] =>    Innova
    [18] =>    Landcruiser
)```


From this Skoda and Maruti Suzuki are parent categories. 
Is there any way to limit parent categories with their and get all the childrens?
Expecting result is like:

Array
(
    [1] => Skoda
    [2] =>    Kushaq
    [3] =>    Taigun
    [4] => Maruti Suzuki
    [5] =>    Swift
    [9] =>       Swift VXI
    [11] =>          Swift VXI ABS
    [10] =>       Swift LXI
    [6] =>    Baleno
    [7] =>       Baleno RS
    [8] =>       Baleno LS
)
````

Thanks in advance.Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: There is no such "built-in" functionality other than scoping, which ties into undocumented functionality in form of a behavior option named `scope`, which applies to many of the tree behavior functions. Basically you add a column to every record, give it a specific value per tree, which you can then pass conditions for. If that isn't going to work for your use-case, then you'd have to manually query the records, and pass the results to `formatTreeList()`. If you explain what exactly you mean by "limiting" (pagination? filtering by root name? ...), maybe someone can come up with an example.